# How to create this kind of panels in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, osx-chameleon

Github released their own native client on the Mac.  Upon launching the client, you will get this welcome panel:
[image: GitHub Mac Client]

In Cocoa framework, how to create something like it?
On a side note, they don't use Cocoa. They use [Chameleon Project](http://chameleonproject.org/)

Comment: This may as well be a WebKit view showing a static embedded webpage. It's by far the easiest way to make a view look like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NSImageView would display a background image just fine ...